# Как правильно организовать многофайловый проект с взаимными зависимостями между классами?

Tags: c++, g++, cmake, clion

Есть проект игрушки с использованием SFML. Работаю в Clion, компилятор g++. Вылетают совсем абсурдные на мой взгляд ошибки, как на скриншоте. Опытные программисты, помогите, пожалуйста. Что я делаю не так?
[Ссылка на проект на github.](https://github.com/IgorVelikiy/ONE_versus_ALL)
[image: Ошибка компилятора]

Comment: Поскольку в Bullet.h иммеется лишь упоминание классов Zombie и Hero, а используются лишь указатели на них - определение (то есть включение хедер файлов) для этих классов не нужно. Достаточно forward declaration. Следует заменить `#include "Zombie.h"` на `class Zombie;` `class Hero;`. Инклюды отправляются в cpp файл. И везде, где в h-файлах достаточно forward declaration используете его, чтобы было минимум зависимостей.

Comment: Почему у Вас в Hero.h закомментирован Living.h?

Comment: Пытался понять логику CLion'a. Т.к. что включал его, что не включал - ошибки именно там нет.

Comment: Artemy Vysotsky, спасибо огромное! Теперь все скомпилировалось. Вопрос решен.